# How to correctly Deserialize obects while catching errors

Tags: actionscript-3, serialization, air

I have a class **DataFile** which is the top level class that I am serializing. **DataFile** contains an **ArrayCollection** which in-turn contains objects which extend **ArrayData**, each which overrides *readExternal* in different ways.

Over the course of the development the **ArrayData** object from version 1.0 is now different than the **ArrayData** object in version 1.1.

This causes deserialization to fail, most often with a null object error.

This is expected behavior. What I would like to happen is that in cases where an error occurs the object would simply be ignored and we would continue deserialization.

To effect this I have thrown try..catch logic into the deserialization for the **ArrayData**

```
override public function readExternal(input:IDataInput):void {
  try {
    testvalue = input.readObject();
    newTestValue = input.readObject(); //a value that is not a part of the file being deserialized
  catch(e:Error){
    //an error occurred, but just keep going
  }
}
```

I was hoping that this would allow the deserialization chain to continue doing its thing and then would allow me to clean up the broken data after everything has been deserialized.

The problem I am now having is that the serialization of the **ArrayCollection** fails immediately after an error is caught in a bad **ArrayData** object with a index out of bounds error.

> Error #2006: The supplied index is out
>   of bounds.

I have tried faking data in the catch portion of te **ArrayData** object but nothing works. I don't know why the error is bubbling up the deserialization chain and I do not know how to prevent this.

If anyone has any ideas on where I should go next in an attempt to resolve this issue I would appreciate the feedback.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: did you tried to put a trace in the catch-block to see whether the error is catched at all by this try-catch-block ?

Comment: Yes, the catch-block does catch the error.